# Conversion to double from cell is not possible

Tags: matlab, user-interface, type-conversion, cell

I am using a gui and in my button click function I try to plot something, but I get the error

```
Error using plot
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
```

I'm new to matlab, so not really sure why, I got the first value of the list that the gui gives me. The line that doesn't work is the last one.

```
function calc_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to calc (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% blah = get(handles.calc, 'string');
set(handles.x2, 'string', 'hi');
XX1 = get(handles.x1, 'string');
YY1 = get(handles.y1, 'string');
RR1 = get(handles.r1, 'string');

XX2 = get(handles.x2, 'string');
YY2 = get(handles.y2, 'string');
RR2 = get(handles.r2, 'string');

XX3 = get(handles.x3, 'string');
YY3 = get(handles.y3, 'string');
RR3 = get(handles.r3, 'string');

% x1 = X1{1}; 
x1 = XX1;    
y1 = YY1{1}; %needed to do this because I was getting an error that said
r1 = RR1{1}; % Undefined function 'abs' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
%x2 = X2{1};
x2 = XX2;
y2 = YY2{1};
r2 = RR2{1};
x3 = XX3{1};
y3 = YY3{1};
r3 = RR3{1};

min = r1;


disp(['r1 ' num2str(min)]);
disp(['r2 ' num2str(r2)]);
if(min > r2)
    min = r2;
end
if (min > r3)
    min = r3;
end

temp = min;
min = temp/10;

disp(x1);
hold on
a = plot (x1,y1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why.
I needed to do

```
x2 = XX2{1};
```

to get the first value of the array that the gui returns

Comment: Yes. You were trying to plot `x1` in the last line, but you cannot plot an entire cell array in that way. Once you too just the first element of the cell array, which contained an array of double, the plot command could work. Glad you figured it out, and thanks for posting your solution.